# Hangman-like Python Program

Tags: python, string, loops

NOTE: I am unable to use lists to solve this. This is a challenge for string manipulation.

It should have the user input a word and display asterisks, filling in the letters guessed like hangman

```
def word_guess():


    word = input('Enter the word: ')

    print('\n'*100)

    print('Guess the word: ')

    guess_string='*' * len(word)

    print(guess_string)

    letters_left = word
    letters_guessed = '*' * len(word)

    while '*' in letters_guessed:
        new_left = ''
        new_display = ''
        guessed = ''
        guess = input('Enter a letter: ')

        guessed += guess

        while guess in guessed:
            print('Already guessed. Try again.')
            guess = input('Enter guess: ')

        for char in letters_left:
            if guess == char:
              new_display += char
              new_left += '*'
            else:
              new_display += '*'
              new_left += char
        letters_guessed = new_display

        letters_left = new_left

        print(new_display)
```

This produces the following:

[image: notice how the entire input is spelled out and the asterisks don't disappear]

This is very disconcerting for me. My last strategy to conquer this problem.

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: Output should be revealing the word through the asterisks, this is taking the input and returning the asterisks without saving the progress the user made during the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the particular problem you seem to be asking about:

```
guessed = ''
guess = input('Enter a letter: ')

guessed += guess

while guess in guessed:
```

Think about what this does. It sets `guessed` to `''`. Then, if I type `a`, it sets `guessed` to `'' + 'a'`, which is `'a'`. Then, `while guess in guessed:` is going to keep asking me for new guesses until one of them isn't in `'a'`.

That obviously isn't doing anything useful. I *think* what you were trying to do is something like this:

```
guessed = '' # before the loop

while '*' in letters_guessed:
    new_left = ''
    new_display = ''
    guess = input('Enter a letter: ')

    while guess in guessed:
        print('Already guessed. Try again.')
        guess = input('Enter guess: ')

    guessed += guess # after we've accepted the guess
```

Now, `guessed` is all of the guesses I've tried to so far, not counting the one I'm trying now, instead of being just the guess I'm trying now, so the `while` loop makes more sense.

Of course your program has multiple other bugs, so it's still not going to work without fixing them, but this should get you past that one.

---

Meanwhile, you should consider doing one of the following:

- Add some temporary `print` calls to dump out the relevant variables wherever you're not sure what's happening.
- Run the code in the debugger, so you can break in and explore what's going on at the place you're confused by.
- Run the code in a visualizer like [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#), so you can graphically see what's happening to all of your variables step by step.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of strange things here that would probably help to fix.

1. you are resetting `guessed` to `''` every time through he loop.  Probably want that outside.
2. you set `guessed += guess` and then immediately follow that with `while guess in guessed`... so you're always going to get the `Already guessed` prompt at least once
3. I'm not exactly sure what the point of `letters_left` is
4. instead of `new_display += '*'` in the `else` clause, you probably want to pull the display chars from `letters_guessed` so you're showing all letters that have been guessed (and `*` for the ones that have not)